# Upload Different Video Formats

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I know if a video was taken with a phone, camcorder, or something else? I have an intranet site done in C# that users upload educational videos. The videos were taken with smartphone, cameras, VCR converted to digital format etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file header, in search for info it contains, for example a MPEG video has a header format like this: [MPEG HEADER FORMAT](http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/mpeghdrs.html).

Sometimes the devices puts some information about itself in "user data" section, like a camera, who sometimes put the camera model.

-->Edit<-- How we can read header?

for example, if you have this format

[image: Header]

you can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace HeaderReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] bytesFile = new byte[7]; // Read the first 7 Bytes
            using (FileStream FileS = File.OpenRead("MyFile")) //the uploaded file
            {
                FileS.Read(bytesFile, 0, 7);
                FileS.Close();
            }
            string data = BitConverter.ToString(bytesFile); //convert data to get info
            Console.WriteLine("This is the data:" + data);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope to be helpful.

Comment: How can we view the header ?

Comment: I was searching some more about my question. I haven't tried it yet but would ExifTool give me the information?

Comment: Yes, but i always recommend do this type of procedures by yourself to get only the information you want.